# Filtering multiValued Field in Solr

Tags: solr

How can i search inside array of a multivalued field
My Data is like this

```
 <str name="Key">8</str>
       <arr name="city">
          <str>Achabal (NAC)</str>
          <str>Addi Gam</str>
          <str>Adeh Hall</str>
          <str>Aho Paisan</str>
          <str>Akin Gam</str>
          <str>Akura</str>
          .......
        </arr>
       <str name="state">Chandigarh</str>
```

I want to search inside city filed i am trying the query as below

```
q=city:*Ak* AND state:Chandigarh <br>
```

But not working 
Above mentioned data is single document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multivalued fields have no difference with monovalued field (from query perspective). Note that in your query there's an error: SOLR doesn't support using a * symbol as the first character of a search.

See links below

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory
http://solr.pl/en/2010/12/20/wildcard-queries-and-how-solr-handles-them
http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

You should not use & in your query but + or %20 (space) instead. & separates url query parameters and state stuff will not be passed as value for q.

Try `q=city:*Ak*+state:Chandigarh` or `q=city:*Ak* state:Chandigarh`.

What you also probably would like to do is use filter query instead of query parameter here:
 `q=city*Ak*&fq=state:Chandigarh`

This will query for all cities with 'Ak' and limit results only to ones with state='Chandigarh'

Comment: Thanks for the reply But have tried all the option you mentioned above in every case it is returning all the values from city for a particular state

Comment: Are you using N-gram filter? If you are, solr will disregard the state:Chandigarh rather use state:15 , i.e 15 as state ID assuming you can get state ID from a db lookup. When I activate N-gram filter, solr chucks away my non integer field. Seen by debugging query.- Good Luck.